# Setting height of a chart in Apexcharts

Tags: apexcharts

I am trying to set the height of a chart in Apexcharts, but it seems to only work in responsive mode, no matter what I try.

Any idea?

Here is a [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-basic-example-106dq?file=/src/App.js) (it's the basic example from their docs, plus I added a height).
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Have you tried setting the `height` on the `Chart`, i.e. `<Chart options={this.state.options} series={this.state.series} type="bar" width="500" height="100" />`

Comment: Man I love you, no I didn't try!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to add the `height` to the actual `Chart` component like the width that has already been set in your example.

Here's an example of setting the `height` to `100px`

`<Chart options={this.state.options} series={this.state.series} type="bar" width="500" height="100" />`

Documentation - [Props](https://apexcharts.com/docs/react-charts/)

[image]

Comment: Thx, does it say so in the docs? In that case I totally missed it

Comment: It looks like it's in the [documentation](https://apexcharts.com/docs/react-charts/) under **Props**

Comment: Ah, right, thx. When I clicked on "height" it would bring me to a configuration option, so i just went down that way.